# возобновление загрузки C#

Tags: c#, загрузка

Не могу сообразить как сделать возобновление загрузки при потере соединения интернета.Вроде бы такой код заново скачивает файл, а не дозагружает. Как быть?

```
WebClient load = new WebClient();
        string uri = "http://grt.ru/tmp.exe";
        string fname = @"C:\tmp.exe";
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Началась загрузка файла\n" + fname + "\nпо адресу: " + "\n" + uri);
            load.DownloadFile(uri, fname);
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {

            var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
            var fi = new FileInfo(fname);
            var havePart = fi.Exists;
            if (havePart)
                request.AddRange(fi.Length);
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                var partialDownload = havePart && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
                using (var file = File.Open(fname, partialDownload ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create))
                using (var net = response.GetResponseStream()) 
                    net.CopyTo(file);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Download comleted!");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Что значит "возобновление"? Чтобы возобновить что-то, надо это что-то остановить сначала...

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл дополнить. Например при потери соединения интернета. Мысли такие, необходимо записать количество скачанных байтов. При потере соединения возобновить с последнего скачанного байта.

Comment: Вы знакомы с концепцией исключений (exceptions)?

Comment: Вы про это имеете ввиду?( Добавил в описание)

Comment: в WebRequest/WebResponse есть возможность скачивания по частям. Можно использовать вместо WebClient

Comment: Имел ввиду HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю как с этим работать

Comment: При закрытии программы и повторном разрыве соединении скачивает заново.